# How to check uwsgi with gevent at socket file in k8s readinessProbe and livenessProbe

Tags: kubernetes, uwsgi, gevent

I have a flask app with uwsgi and gevent.
Here is my `app.ini`
How could I write readinessProbe and livenessProbe on kubernetes to check to flask app?

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
chdir = /usr/src/app/
chmod-socket = 666
module = flasky
callable = app
master = false
processes = 1
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
gevent = 1000
listen = 1024
```

Comment: You can execute any shell command for readiness and liveness probes. How would you achieve your goal in bash?

Comment: @peedee Thank you for check my problem. Frankly, I do not quite understand uwsgi. So I don't know how to check uwsgi is living with shell command.

Comment: Then that's what you need to figure out. A readinessProbe will do nothing else but execute a shell command that you have to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are really asking is "How to health check a uWSGI application". There are some example tools to do this. Particularly:

- https://github.com/andreif/uwsgi-tools
- https://github.com/che0/uwping
- https://github.com/m-messiah/uwget

The `uwsgi-tools` project seems to have the most complete example at https://github.com/andreif/uwsgi-tools/issues/2#issuecomment-345195583. In a Kubernetes Pod spec context this might end up looking like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-exec
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp
    image: myimage
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - uwsgi_curl
        - -H
        - Host:host.name
        - /path/to/unix/socket
        - /health
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```

This would also assume your application responded to `/health` as a health endpoint.

Comment: Yap, I think you got my point. I just try to find a way to not install these tools and test uwsgi, but it looks like kubernetes doesn't support this.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure `uWSGI` to serve both `uwsgi-socket` along side `http-socket`, and only expose the `uwsgi-socket` to the `k8s service`.

In this case your `uwsgi.ini` would looks something like:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
chdir = /usr/src/app/
chmod-socket = 666
module = flasky
callable = app
master = false
processes = 1
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
gevent = 1000
listen = 1024

http-socket = 0.0.0.0:5050
```

And assuming you have `/health` endpoint in your app, your `k8s manifest` can be something like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-exec
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp
    image: myimage
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /health
        port: 5050
        httpHeaders:
        - name: Custom-Header
          value: Awesome
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```

In this case, your service will be reachable sitting as the upstream at `socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock` via your `k8s service` and the `k8s healthcheck` service can reach your container at `http-socket: 5050`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small readiness check for uwsgi applications: https://github.com/filipenf/uwsgi-readiness-check/

It reads uwsgi's stats socket and checks for queue size. If queue is above a configurable threshold, Pod is marked as "NotReady" until its queue is drained and it can be marked as ready again.

Install it into your container image with:

```
pip install uwsgi-readiness-check
```

and then run the check with something like:

```
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - uwsgi-is-ready
                - --stats-socket
                - /tmp/uwsgi-stats
                - --queue-threshold
                - 0.7
            failureThreshold: 2
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
```

Hope it helps for your use case